# Is it possible to automate the generation of a Visio diagram from a written process?

Tags: microsoft-visio, documentation

I have several projects where process steps need to be written out (i.e, bulleted, numbered), and Visio flowcharts/diagrams need to be created for these processes. I guess Visio is optional, but it is what I am using.

Is there a method or tool whereby I can somehow markup up my process so that the flowchart/diagram can be partially automated (I fully expect that much formatting will still be needed)?

The most similar thing I can think of is the relationship between UML and code, but this is far from a perfect analogy. To restate, I'd like to input a formatted process into "?" and get a flowchart as output.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

That is a very interesting scenario and with Visio's new smart diagram feature now you can automatically create a Basic Flowchart or Cross-Functional Flowchart from your process map data in Excel, in no time.

The feature has not been released yet, however we just announced the early preview of the feature. If you want to try it out and create your diagrams automatically, [sign up now](https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_9MNcyWmZghnDP8x)

[Here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_officeinsider-mso_win10/introducing-early-preview-of-smart-diagrams-from/0d32379d-a303-4805-8165-9b3bce6dc3d1?auth=1) is the feature preview announcement on Microsoft answers forum.

Cheers!
Shashank Gandhi